# Facebook Audience Network - Low impressions (200) on iOS but good in Android 20K

Tags: ios, admob, ads, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

We cannot see impressions on iOS in our monetization, but we can see for android. We are using Admob mediation. Screenshot is attached.